# Referencing a property of a custom object in one typescript file to another

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to reference a property in the array of custom building objects 'id' in the list building ts file to another ts file(building information ts file). My goal is to use the 'id' property to change the picture in building information page based on the selected id. However, I am experiencing some issues of referencing the 'id' from another file.

list-buildings.page.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let building of buildingList">
    <img [src]="building.image" (click)="goToFunBuildings(building.id)">
    <ion-label>{{ building.label }}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

list-buildings.page.ts- creating an array of custom building Objects

```
    public buildingList: any[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            label: 'Campus Gym!',
            image: '/assets/img/gym.png',
        }
        ..... //rest of buildings
    ];
```

buildingInfo-page.page.ts- this is where I am trying to reference ID to display the correct picture for the corresponding label if it is clicked

```
goToBuilding(){
    if(building.id == 1){
      this.angularLogo= "/assets/img/library.jpg";
    }

    if(building.id == 2){
      this.angularLogo= "/assets/img/gym.jpg";
    }


    return this.angularLogo;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your configuration wether you show a separate page for building details or you just show details component near the listing.

Lets assume you show building details inside listing component

**list-buildings.page.html**

```
<!-- listing -->
<building-details [url]="angularLogo"></building-details>
```

You already change `angularLogo` inside `goToBuilding()`.

and here is a simple BuildingDetailsComponent

**building-details.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'bs-building-details',
  templateUrl: './building-details.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class BuildingDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input url: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**building-details.component.html**

```
<img [src]="url" />
```

Read more about [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)

Comment: How will this work if I am using building details as a separate page?

Answer (score 0):

To share data between components, use a service. Create an Angular service that contains this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BuildingService {

    public buildingList: any[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            label: 'Campus Gym!',
            image: '/assets/img/gym.png',
        }
        ..... //rest of buildings
    ];
}
```

Inject the service into both components that need this information, and then access this data through the service.

```
export class BuildingListComponent {
  get buildingList(): string {
    return this.dataService.buildingList;
  }

  constructor(private buildingService: BuildingService ) {

  }
}
```

I have an example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simpleservice-deborahk

You can then pass the selected id from one component to the next as a parameter on the URL. The other component can also inject the service and access the appropriate building from the list.

```
export class BuildingInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  currentBuilding;

  constructor(private buildingService: BuildingService ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const param = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (param) {
      const id = +param;
      this.currentBuilding = this.buildingService.buildingList.find(item => item.id === id);
    }
  }
}
```

[NOTE: None of this code was tested or syntax checked]

Comment: This is too complicated. All you need is @Input() binding.